# Variable scope problems in eval()'d code + included PHP-file

Tags: ubercart

In [Ubercart](http://drupal.org/project/ubercart)'s **Conditional actions**, I can add my own PHP code to an action called "*Execute custom PHP code*". In this PHP code, I can use two variables: `$order` and `$account`.

To test it, I put some codes in the beginning of the textarea:

```
drupal_set_message('before including file....');
drupal_set_message('isset($account): <pre>'.var_export(isset($account), TRUE).'</pre>');
drupal_set_message('isset($order): <pre>'.var_export(isset($order), TRUE).'</pre>');
drupal_set_message('isset($order->products): <pre>'.var_export(isset($order->products), TRUE).'</pre>');
```

OK, it outputs the following:

```
before including file....
isset($account):
true
isset($order):
true
isset($order->products):
true
```

That's correct, so I can use `$account` and `$order` variables without a problem.
BUT I would rather like to put my codes into a separate file and include it here - so I would like to use the mentioned `$account` and `$order` variables in the file.
BUT after including the file, these variables don't exist in the file's scope, even if I type the line `global $account, $order;` at the beginning of the file!

So for example there's a module called 'test_module', and the file is in the module's php directory, its name is '`testPurchase.inc`'. I put the following code into the custom "*Execute custom PHP code*" textarea:

```
drupal_set_message('before including file....');
drupal_set_message('isset($account): <pre>'.var_export(isset($account), TRUE).'</pre>');
drupal_set_message('isset($order): <pre>'.var_export(isset($order), TRUE).'</pre>');
drupal_set_message('isset($order->products): <pre>'.var_export(isset($order->products), TRUE).'</pre>');

$module_name = 'test_module';
$filepath = 'php/testPurchase';
$file_extension = 'inc';

module_load_include($file_extension, $module_name, $filepath);
```

And the content of the `testPurchase.inc`:

```
<?php

// checking the existence of the $account and $order variables in 'testPurchase.inc' file...
drupal_set_message('this is already in the included file....');
drupal_set_message('isset($account): <pre>'.var_export(isset($account), TRUE).'</pre>');
drupal_set_message('isset($order): <pre>'.var_export(isset($order), TRUE).'</pre>');
drupal_set_message('isset($order->products): <pre>'.var_export(isset($order->products), TRUE).'</pre>');
```

OK, the file inclusion is correct, but the result is the following:

```
before including file....
isset($account):
true
isset($order):
true
isset($order->products):
true
this is already in the included file....
isset($account):
false
isset($order):
false
isset($order->products):
false
```

So in the 'testPurchase.inc', the `$account` and `$order` variables don't exist.
But why? Shouldn't the scope be the same?

Is the source of the problem that this code is [eval()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php)'d?
**How can I get around this issue, to keep my code in the file, but be able to use the two mentioned variables without the need to define a predicate via my custom module?

I'm primarily curious to know the reason why this happens.**

P.S. I've already tried it without using the `module_load_include()` function, with the 'pure' usage of the `require_once()` function, and the result is just the same.

---

**EDIT**: *Let me explain why the occurrance of the mentioned problem of `eval()` in Drupal's to-be-evaluated textbox isn't quite clear to me!*

I don't think this is the way how PHP should work. So I tested it in my own separate files: I created a file with defining some variables in it, and then included another file in the regular way, and after that, I included a file via `eval()` - in both cases, I checked the existence and value of the earlier defined variables in the included files.
**The result: the scope was the same after including these files - so I could use the earlier defined variables in the included files without any kind of problem!!**

***Let me show you the results of my tests!***

So here comes the first file for testing the variables, where I include the different files via different methods, I think the code is quite clear:

`test_vars_normally_and_eval.php`:

```php
<?php

    $variable_1 = 12345;
    $variable_2 = 'Test stuff';

    require_once('test_vars_require_normal.php');

    echo '<hr />';

    $test_eval_1 = '
        $eval_variable_1 = 12; 
        $eval_variable_2 = 49;
        echo "<h3><u>eval() - appending var. testing file as a string with file_get_contents():</u></h3>"; 
        ?>'.file_get_contents('test_vars_require_eval.php');

    eval( $test_eval_1 );

    $test_eval_2 = '
        $eval_variable_1 = 666;
        $eval_variable_2 = 999;
        echo "<h3><u>eval() - including var. testing file with require_once() in eval():</u></h3>";
        require_once("test_vars_require_eval.php");
        ';

    eval( $test_eval_2 );
```

`test_vars_require_normal.php`, the file for a regular inclusion with `require_once()`:

```php
<?php

    echo '<h3><u>testing variables after a regular require_once():</u></h3>';
    echo '<b>isset($variable_1):</b><pre>'.var_export( isset($variable_1), TRUE).'</pre>';
    if(isset($variable_1)){
        echo '<b>$variable_1:</b><pre>'.var_export( $variable_1, TRUE).'</pre>';
    }
    echo '<b>isset($variable_2):</b><pre>'.var_export( isset($variable_2), TRUE).'</pre>';
    if(isset($variable_2)){
        echo '<b>$variable_2:</b><pre>'.var_export( $variable_2, TRUE).'</pre>';
    }
```

`test_vars_require_eval.php`, the file which is included via `eval()`:

```php
<?php

    echo '<b>isset($eval_variable_1):</b><pre>', var_export(isset($eval_variable_1), TRUE), '</pre>';
    if(isset($eval_variable_1)){
        echo '<b>$eval_variable_1:</b><pre>', var_export($eval_variable_1, TRUE), '</pre>';
    }

    echo '<b>isset($eval_variable_2):</b><pre>', var_export(isset($eval_variable_2), TRUE), '</pre>';
    if(isset($eval_variable_2)){
        echo '<b>$eval_variable_2:</b><pre>', var_export($eval_variable_2, TRUE), '</pre>';
    }

    echo '<hr />';
```

## ***AND THE FINAL OUTPUT IS THE [FOLLOWING](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cwW8U.png):***

**testing variables after a regular require_once():**

**isset($variable_1):**

```
true
```

**$variable_1:**

```
12345
```

**isset($variable_2):**

```
true
```

$variable_2:

```
'Test stuff'
```

**eval() - appending var. testing file as a string with file_get_contents():**

**isset($eval_variable_1):**

```
true
```

**$eval_variable_1:**

```
12
```

**isset($eval_variable_2):**

```
true
```

**$eval_variable_2:**

```
49
```

**eval() - including var. testing file with require_once() in eval():**

**isset($eval_variable_1):**

```
true
```

**$eval_variable_1:**

```
666
```

**isset($eval_variable_2):**

```
true
```

**$eval_variable_2:**

```
999
```

Answer (score 2):

This is probably more a PHP than Drupal question.

Anyways the file itself should not be what's executed, instead you should use functions where you can pass variables around.

so your `.inc` should be altered:

```
<?php
function test_purchase($account, $order) {
  // checking the existence of the $account and $order variables in'testPurchase.inc' file...
  drupal_set_message('this is already in the included file....');
  drupal_set_message('isset($account): <pre>'.var_export(isset($account), TRUE).'</pre>');
  drupal_set_message('isset($order): <pre>'.var_export(isset($order), TRUE).'</pre>');
  drupal_set_message('isset($order->products): <pre>'.var_export(isset($order->products), TRUE).'</pre>');
}
```

and after the include you can do

```
 test_purchase($account, $order);
```

This is the general approach in PHP. Use functions instead of including files and running code

Comment: Yes, you're absolutely right, and this way it does work, thank you! :) But don't you have any idea why the mentioned variables are not available like "global" variables in the included file's scope (even if it's only PHP-related question)?

Comment: @Sk8erPeter Simple answer is that this is how PHP functions. If the answer helped you, remember to mark as accepted or up vote :)

Comment: I know, I know. :) +1: I voted up your answer, because suggesting to put it in a function was useful - and it actually works. The reason why I didn't accept your answer yet (!) is that I don't think this is how PHP works, and I'm really curious to know the real answer to this problem: please see my updated answer after the "EDIT" part, I made some tests for checking the existence of my earlier defined variables in the included files! The tests seem to confirm what I expected earlier - these variables are available in the included files, but it doesn't work in Drupal's textarea!Any ideas why?

Comment: So if you could explain the real reasons why the same method doesn't work when these codes are evaluated in Drupal, I would immediately accept your answer as the "one and only" solution. :)